# Convert Map<String, Set> to POJO using Jackson / Gson API

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, jackson-databind

I'm using a third-party API returns data as **Map<String, Set<?>>** which is in JSON format, where key is a String and is same as class variable and Set contains related value, which will be String and only one value is expected even though it is a Set.

Now one way is to loop through Map and use Reflection to populate POJO.

I was wondering if Jackson / Gson API could be used to populate POJO. I tried both but values are not populated in POJO.

```
JSON:
{
    "Id": [
        "345"
    ],
    "Name": [
        "John"
    ]
}

POJO:
public class Employee implements Serializable {
  private String id;
  private String name;

  // getter / setter
}

My Code:

Map<String, Set<?>> data = someObject.getDataSet();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Employee employee = mapper.convertValue(data, Employee.class);
System.out.println(employee);
```

**Update**:
I tried following but still POJO is empty

```
Map<String, Set<?>> data = someObject.getDataSet();

Map<String, String> map = data.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue().iterator().next().toString()));

Employee employee = null;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
Employee = mapper.convertValue(map, Employee.class);
System.out.println(employee);

Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(map);
Employee = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, Employee.class);
System.out.println(employee);
```

Comment: [
        "345"
    ] indicates its a array, so you can change String id; to List<Strinng> id

Comment: @NehaK The question suggests that he wants to keep it separately, not in a list

Comment: @PiotrŻmudzin You are right. I want to populate POJO even though values are Array.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be specific and I don't think there is a built-in way to do this, you could load the entire tree using Jackson and just map the nodes to POJOs

example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);
Iterator<JsonNode> ids = root.get("Id").iterator();
Iterator<JsonNode> names = root.get("Names").iterator();

while (ids.hasNext()) {
    String id = ids.next().asText();
    String name = null;
    if (names.hasNext()) {
        name = names.next().asText();
    }
    employees.add(new Employee(id, name));
}
```

another way:

```
JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(json);
        
Map<String, Iterator<JsonNode>> iterators = new HashMap<>();
root.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(name -> iterators.put(name, root.get(name).iterator()));

List<Map<String, String>> allAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Iterator<JsonNode>> e : iterators.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue().hasNext()) {
            attributes.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().next().asText());
        }
    }
    if (attributes.size() != 0) {
        allAttributes.add(attributes);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

List<Employee> employees = allAttributes.stream()
    .map(this::mapToEmployee)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then you add method that maps property-value to POJO

You could also do this without mapping method:

```
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

Map<String, Iterator<JsonNode>> iterators = new HashMap<>();
root.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(name -> iterators.put(name, 
root.get(name).iterator()));

List<JsonNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    boolean hasNext = false;
    ObjectNode node = mapper.createObjectNode();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Iterator<JsonNode>> e : iterators.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue().hasNext()) {
            hasNext = true;
            node.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().next().asText());
        }
    }
    if (hasNext) {
        nodes.add(node);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
nodes.forEach(node -> {
    try {
        employees.add(mapper.treeToValue(node, Employee.class));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: there will be 30-35 attributes, your example won't work.